# Javascript Type Error :Object has no method each

Tags: javascript

am Trying to submit labwork that has background check(  visible and an invisible test)

here is my codes

```
var input = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
        input[i - 1] = i;
    }


    var fizzBuzz = function(what, inputList) {
        return inputList.filter(function(item, index) {
            return !(item % what);
        });
    };


    var fizzes = fizzBuzz(3, input);
    var buzzes = fizzBuzz(5, input);
    var fizzbuzzes = fizzBuzz(15, input);


    var transform = function(to, onWhat) {
        return function(item, index) {
            onWhat[item - 1] = to; 
        };
    };

    fizzes.each(transform("Fizz", input));
    buzzes.each(transform("Buzz", input));
    fizzbuzzes.each(transform("FizzBuzz", input));


    input.each(function(item, index) {
        document.write(item + "<br>");
    });
```

below is the error

THERE IS AN ERROR/BUG IN YOUR CODE
Results:

/home/ubuntu/Applications/andelabs-server/tmp/andelabs_5765ac1ee83de519007349eb_565c28fd9c306a14009680f2.js:25
    fizzes.each(transform("Fizz", input));
           ^
TypeError: Object 3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99 has no method 'each'
    at Object. (/home/ubuntu/Applications/andelabs-server/tmp/andelabs_5765ac1ee83de519007349eb_565c28fd9c306a14009680f2.js:25:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (/home/ubuntu/Applications/andelabs-server/tmp/5765ac1ee83de519007349eb-565c28fd9c306a14009680f2-test.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

Comment: And what is your question? The error tells you that arrays don't have an `each` method. What is unclear about it? If you want to know which methods exist, look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2).

Comment: My question is how to makes my code work with each() or any other fucntion

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method `each()` for arrays. You can use `Array.prototype.forEach`

```
fizzes.forEach(transform("Fizz", input));
buzzes.forEach(transform("Buzz", input));
fizzbuzzes.forEach(transform("FizzBuzz", input));


input.forEach(function(item, index) {
    document.write(item + "<br>");
});
```

Comment: `each()` is for jquery, `forEach()` is for JavaScript arrays

Comment: Zohaib thank you for the concern. But still getting error   TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Comment: @Muhammad What kind of error? Can you update your question?

Comment: Bradz Tech Thank you it work! but getting another error #document not define  HERE IS AN ERROR/BUG IN YOUR CODE
Results: 

/home/ubuntu/Applications/andelabs-server/tmp/andelabs_5765ac1ee83de519007349eb_565c28fd9c306a14009680f2.js:30
  document.write(item + "
");
  ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined            please read my code

Comment: @Muhammad It is because you are not running that script in browser so you can't do this `document.write(item + "<br>");`

Comment: Thanks Zuhaib. the error has gone but still getting another error     Total Specs: 8 Total Failures: 8
1 .  Fizz Buzz tests should return `Fizz` for number divisible by 3
TypeError: Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined
2 .  Fizz Buzz tests should return `Buzz` for number divisible by 5
 here is the code that perfom test on my codes(posted abve)                  
  describe("Fizz Buzz tests ", function() {
  it("should return `Fizz` for number divisible by 3", function() {
    expect(fizzBuzz(3)).toBe('Fizz');
  });